# Always first filtered selected on Quasar Select

Tags: vue.js, quasar

I am using Quasar Framework and using the Q-Select with filter.
I would like to the first filtered option always be already marked, because then if I hit enter, the first will selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I found out how to achieve this in a generic way.
The second parameter on the function update received at filterFn is the instance of QSelect itself.

Hence, we can use

```
ref.setOptionIndex(-1);
ref.moveOptionSelection(1, true);
```

To keep the focus on the first filtered element, regardless of multiselect or not.

The final code is something like

```
filterFn(val, update) {
        update(
            () => {
                const needle = val.toLocaleLowerCase();
                this.selectOptions = this.qSelectOptions.filter(v => v.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(needle) > -1);
            },
            ref => {

                ref.setOptionIndex(-1);
                ref.moveOptionSelection(1, true);
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one option to achieve this is set model value in the filter method if filtered options length is >0.

```
filterFn (val, update, abort) {
  update(() => {
    const needle = val.toLowerCase()
    this.options = stringOptions.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle) > -1)

    if(this.options.length>0 && this.model!=''){
      this.model = this.options[0];
    }
  })
}
```

Codepen - https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/QWjYoNo

Comment: it works partially, but I was looking for a generic solution, being able to use multiselect also. i found out that the second parameter received on update is the instance of QSelect itself. Hence, we can use setOptionIndex and moveOptionsSelected to achieve this is a generic way.